# Multiple Servers connecting to APNS with same SSL certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, apple-push-notifications

We are launching a product which has both a client and server piece. The client would be available over App Store and server can be downloaded from our company's web site. 
The server part would be installed by individual customer on their own network.

While implementing Push notifications, it cam to my notice that the server talks to Apple Push Notification Service and validates itself with the SLL Certificate.

The question is, can all our customer use the same SSL certificates and connect to APNS to push notifications on their devices?

Please note that there is only on client app, that is available through app store.

Comment: So, you have a certificate bundled with your server, and you expect all your customers to use the same certificate? Is this what you're asking?

Comment: @raman-walia what was the final solution you adopted? I am in the same situation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install the apple push notification certificate downloaded from developper center on multiple servers at the same time.

Comment: The question would how to update the certificate if it is expired. Will that violate the any agreement with Apple?