# Is there any limitation of maximum number of servers which can connect to APNS with same SSL certificate?

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

This question related to the below post. But that does not have complete answer of my doubt.

[Multiple Servers connecting to APNS with same SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075795/multiple-servers-connecting-to-apns-with-same-ssl-certificate)

My question is how many servers can use the same SSL certificate? is it unlimited?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Servers connecting to APNS with same SSL certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075795/multiple-servers-connecting-to-apns-with-same-ssl-certificate)

Comment: "does not have complete answer of my doubt" Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Unlimited in theory.

In practice your bandwidth and server power is going to provide a cap.