# How to ask customer to apply for APNS push certification (no MDM capability)

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I followed instruction to generate a development APNS certificate and I am able to send the push notification successfully to my iPhone.  Our application would be deployed on premise in customer environment, so I am looking for what instruction I should give customer to generate the APNS production certificate.  Based on my search at this point, it is all about MDM APNS certificate generation and here is from [Apple MDM web site](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/it-center/deployment-mdm.html):

> 1.Contact your MDM vendor to request a signed Certificate Signing Request (CSR). Your vendor will sign a CSR and deliver it to you.
>
> 2.Once you have a signed CSR from your vendor, visit identity.apple.com/pushcert and sign in with a verified Apple ID.
>
> 3.Click "Create a Certificate” and agree to the Terms of Use.
>
> 4.Select your signed CSR and click upload. After a moment, your certificate will be available for download.
>
> 5.This certificate can now be uploaded to your MDM server for use with the Apple Push Notification service.

However we don't want to be a MDM vendor, we just want to send push notification from server application to our iOS app which would be used by customer.

So do we have other choices? Or should we just package our production certificate with our solution to deploy in customer env? Somehow I didn't find information on internet for my case.

Comment: could anyone help here? Here is a similar link http://openradar.appspot.com/11883652 (APNS doesn't facilitate sending notifications from third parties). Or am I missing sth here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one is answering, I am answering myself.

Based on this link [Multiple Servers Connecting to APNS with same SSL certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075795/multiple-servers-connecting-to-apns-with-same-ssl-certificate?rq=1), we just need to distribute our production APNS certificate to customer. I guess we would need to update the production certificate on customer site when it is about to expire.  By the way, it is also possible to have different production APNS certificates for different customer [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365302/is-it-possible-to-create-multiple-ssl-certificates-for-providers-that-send-apns/15902579#15902579), I guess challenge would be how to manage those certificates when there are a lot.

It is highly welcome for any comments if you have experience in this area.